# EOFException in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

If I'm using 2 users for a thread group, first 2 test data are captured through CSV Data Set Config in the 1st iteration, but the next test data are not captured by JMeter in the next consecutive iterations in the playback time. And EOFException is displayed in jmeter log. Can anyone provide me any solution for it ?

**Jmeter log**:

```
*2014/12/16 03:05:23 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: The delay timer was interrupted - probably did not wait as long as intended. 
2014/12/16 03:05:23 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.EOFException 
2014/12/16 03:05:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 200, Server sent no Errorpage 
2014/12/16 03:05:23 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.EOFException 
2014/12/16 03:05:23 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Error Response Code: 200, Server sent no Errorpage*
```

Comment: Have you selected "Recycle on EOF" value in CSV data set config?

Comment: Yes Nachiket. I've used "Recycle on EOF" as "True".

Comment: Are you still the facing the same issue after setting to True for Recycle on EOF parameter? This should not happen. if issue still persists attach snapshot of csv config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possible reasons:

1. You're using wrong path to CSV file (the most frequent cause is using relative CSV file path without being sure in current JMeters working directory). Solution is: **use full paths where possible**.
2. You have "Recycle on EOF" set to "false" in your CSV Data Set Config

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more details on where to place and how to properly configure CSV Data Set Config test element.